# How do I use the Discord OAuth2 guild.join scope to make a user join a server?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

I have been making a Discord Application that uses the OAuth2 API from Discord to make a user join a server once they authorise my application - This is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def add_user_to_server(token: str, user_id: str, server_id: str) -> bool:
    url = f'https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/{server_id}/members/{user_id}'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'
    }
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f'User {user_id} added to server with ID {server_id}')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'Error adding user {user_id} to server with ID {server_id}')
        return False



# The callback URL for OAuth2 authorization
@app.route('/auth/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    data = {
        'client_id': '',
        'client_secret': '',
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/callback',
        'scope': 'identify guilds.join'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()
    access_token = response['access_token']

    # Get the user ID from the access token
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/users/@me'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    user_id = response['id']

    # Add the user to the server
    invite_code = '1075365992399650836'
    bot_token = 'sike'
    add_user_to_server(bot_token, user_id, invite_code)

    return 'Successfuly authorised with Discord, you may now close this window.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I recieve no errors from the Flask application, other than a favicon 404 error, which doesn't affect my application, which means that it must be something do with either my code or Discord. My bot is in the server, the error code I recieve in the `add_user_to_server` function is a 400 error, which I believe means that the API has recieved something it wasn't expecting, or something client sided. Whatever it is, I do not know.

I attempted to use some AI, such as the Discord Clyde, ChatGPT and Bard, which did not end in successive results. Bard does not understand discord.py, ChatGPT gave me some code that had some questionable libraries, and Clyde is built off of GPT-3, which is what ChatGPT used to be. I have experimented hundreds of times by this point and can't seem to just get it to click. I tried to put some debug print's in there, but all I got from them was the 400 status code stated in the previous paragraph and the JSON strings that were causing me problems before that I have now fixed.

If anyone knows how to fix this, please, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the acces_token, which is required.

Simple fix:

```py
def add_user_to_server(token: str, user_id: str, server_id: str, access_token: str) -> bool:
    url = f'https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/{server_id}/members/{user_id}'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bot {token}'
    }

    data = {
        "access_token": access_token
    }

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f'User {user_id} added to server with ID {server_id}')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'Error adding user {user_id} to server with ID {server_id}')
        return False
```

And replace `add_user_to_server(bot_token, user_id, invite_code)` by `add_user_to_server(bot_token, user_id, invite_code, access_token)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying to figure this out for over 2 weeks now. You are a life saver.